# Change and get value from function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Here is what I want to do but with another um... technique/method. The first one is working, the second is not:

```
<script>
function hello(){
    var number = document.getElementById("omg").innerHTML;
    if(number==undefined){
    number=0;
    }
    number++;
    document.getElementById("omg").innerHTML=number;
}

</script>


<input type="submit" value="yeah" onclick="hello()">
<div id="omg"></div>
```

---

Here is the way that I want to do it, the technique that I want to use but its not working.

```
<script>
function hello(){
    var number;
    if(number==undefined){
    number=1;
    }
    document.getElementById("omg").innerHTML=number;
    number++;
}

<input type="submit" value="yeah" onclick="hello()">
<div id="omg"></div>
```

Instead of taking the last value from the div I want to like take it from a string in the function. So the point is that each time I click the button the number increases by one.

Answer (score 1):

ok, you'll need to make number a global variable, not a local variable to your function.  Otherwise every time you call that function, it'll reset number to 1.

```
var number;

function hello(){ 
    if(number==undefined){
      number=1;
    }
    document.getElementById("omg").innerHTML=number;
    number++;
}
```

Comment: YEAH!, it works! thank you!, I have no idea why I didn’t try it

Answer (score 1):

store the initial value in the div itself (saves a declaration, and you have to display something anyway)

```
<input type="submit" value="yeah" onclick="hello();"/>
<div id="omg">0</div>
```

and call the function like:

```
function hello(){
   var t = document.getElementById("omg").innerHTML;
   document.getElementById("omg").innerHTML = parseInt(t,10) + 1;
}
```

**[fiddle with it here](http://jsfiddle.net/vQfmr/1/)**